# AngularJS 1.1.5 $resource.get is not creating XHR request from setTimeout

Tags: http, angularjs, settimeout

I have asked this question on the google forum for AngularJS and haven't heard about it until now. Can someone help me understand what is going on here?

I am trying to periodically refresh a resource and it doesn't seem to be working. I have tracked it until the fact that the promise has been obtained from $http service but the XHR request is never created and fired when the method is invoked in setTimeout. However, if I do the same without setTimeout everything seems to be working just fine.

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hponnu/Z62QN/2/

```
window.root_module = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngResource']);
function MainController($scope, $resource) {
    $scope.buttonClick = function () {
        var res = $resource("http://www.google.com");
        res.get({}, function (response) {
            alert("response");
        }, function (err) {
            alert("error");
        });
    }
}
```

Broken JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hponnu/H8aEt/10/

```
window.root_module = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngResource']);
window.count = 0;
function MainController($scope, $resource) {
    $scope.buttonClick = function () {
       setTimeout(function () {
            alert("timeout: " + window.count);
            var res = $resource("http://www.google.com");
            res.get({},
                function (response) {
                    alert("response: " + window.count);
                    window.count++;
                }, function (err) {
                    alert("error: " + window.count);
                    window.count++;
                });
       }, 1000);
    }
```

}

As you will clearly see in the broken jsfiddle the error alert is not fired for the first request unless a click event is triggered by click on the button again. I have started noticing this from AngularJS 1.1.4

Any ideas/suggestions?

PS: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/t28mazamT0E is the link for the Google groups thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use Angularjs's [$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout) instead of `setTimeout()`.

```
function MainController($scope, $resource, $timeout) {
    $scope.buttonClick = function () {
        $timeout(function () {
            ...
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the explanation from the thread on google groups .. "What's happening is that when you use setTimeout, you're actually moving outside the angular $digest. To fix that, once the tmeout is done, do a $scope.$apply(), or better yet - inject the $timeout service and use that instead (identical to setTimeout)" ..

Comment: @ponnu Yep, setTimeout() doesn't handle the scopy.apply().